# Windows CMD TYPE command

Tags: command, window

I am learning from a tutorial and it used this command `type NUL > introduction.js` . I searched online TYPE is a command, i know > is redirection operation and last is the name of the file. And it creates an empty file. I dont't know the function of NUL but its equivalent to dev/nul of UNIX.

But can someone summarize the whole command in parts and what is the advantage of doing this instead of echo or other commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CMD help:

```
type /?
Displays the contents of a text file or files.

TYPE [drive:][path]filename
```

and NUL I think is an empty file symbol. so,

```
type NUL > introduction.js
```

reads the content of NUL "Which is an empty file", and write it to `introduction.js`
conclusion:

**You are creating an empty `introduction.js` file.**

Answer (score 11):

In Windows command Prompt:

both ***type*** & ***echo*** can create a file

for creating empty file, for example a text file

```
TYPE nul > pathNewFile.txt

Echo > pathNewFile.txt
```

for adding content to new or existing file by ***Echo***

```
Echo some text > pathNewOrExistingFile.txt
```

and for ***Type*** it puts content of another file

```
TYPE pathExistingFile.txt > pathNewOrExistingFile.txt
```

and in both of them for appending content instead of overriding content
we use ***>>*** for ***>***

```
Echo some text >> pathFileName.txt
```

Comment: Your post is very helpful. Thank you even though I am not the OP.

Comment: ECHO without parameters displays the current echo setting. So the file created by `Echo > pathNewFile.txt` is not empty but contains for example the line "ECHO is on.". COPY can create an empty file as follows: `copy nul empty.txt`